# Why does the first figure be placed aligned bottom and the rest aligned center?

Tags: floats

This is my code for the preamble:

```
\usepackage[nomarkers, nolists, tablesfirst, heads]{endfloat}
```

and this is my main document:

```
\section{Introduction}
Hello this is the introduction section.


\subsection{Subsection 1}
This is subsection 1. This is the line spacing. This is subsection 1. This is the line spacing. This is subsection 1. This is the line spacing. This is subsection 1. This is the line spacing. This is subsection 1. This is the line spacing. This is subsection 1. This is the line spacing.\footnote{This a footnote.}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{figure1.eps} %width=12cm, height=11cm %scale=0.4 width=15cm, height=18cm
\caption{\small A four-period model. Variables in the first best allocation and in the competitive equilibrium without capital controls.}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{figure1.eps} %width=12cm, height=11cm %scale=0.4 width=15cm, height=18cm
\caption{\small A four-period model. Variables in the first best allocation and in the competitive equilibrium without capital controls.}
\label{fig:figure2}
\end{figure}
```

I copy the figure so I get two of them. The first figure is on the figure page with the "Figures" heading and then blank space so that Figure 1 is aligned to the bottom of the page while the next page which contains the Figure 2 is aligned center vertically.

Also, is it possible to put two figures onto one page (if it fits)?

Comment: presumably one figure is at the bottom of a text page (`[b]`) and the other is on a float page (`[p]`) but without an example impossible to say really. Two floats will be placed on a page if they fit. Note you should use `\centering` rather than `\begin{center}` as the environment form adds extra vertical space not needed here as the float adds space.

Comment: I've tried using     \centering but still doesn't work. You are welcome to check my folder files here: http://1drv.ms/1Qid5l7
Tex file: http://1drv.ms/1Qidq7i

Comment: `\centering` is unrelated to vertical positioning but no sorry you need to make the question self contained, not rely on external links.

Comment: I added the source onto the main body.

Comment: OK you are using endfloats so all the floats go to the end, but teh example is not usable as posted as it can not be run to demonstrate the problem. You can use `example-image` which is in distributions for this reason and make a document that shows the problem, otherwise not much can be said really.